# What fires first - Case Assignment rules or Omni-channel Queue Based Routing Salesforce?

Tags: apex

I have enabled Omni-channel and I also have Assignment rules written on Case Object. If in case we have both of them then in what order Cases would be assigned to agent? Will the cases be assigned based on Omni-Channel Queue based routing or via Case Assignment rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called out in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=omnichannel_routing.htm&type=0):

> Automation rules, such as assignment, auto-response, escalation, and workflow rules, aren’t triggered when Omni-Channel routes a work item to an agent and the agent accepts the work.

> When an agent accepts the work and then edits and saves the work item record, automation rules are triggered.

In other words, there is never any conflict between the two configurations; if omni-channel routing is used, it will take precedence and not call the assignment rule at all.

Comment: Perfect!. Does that mean Assignment rules only take place when Case owner is not a queue?

Comment: @sfdc07 Assignment Rules can happen at any time there's a create or edit event and the Assignment Rule Header is set to trigger a rule (e.g. by checking the Assign using Assignment Rule checkbox on edit, or using the flag in the API). The owner at that point may be a user or queue. The ARs won't run only while a user is accepting a case from a queue routed by omni-channel.

Comment: Yep, it makes sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I tried myself to create assignment rules to be triggered after a case is accepted through omni-channel but the AR are never run. I wanted to reassign the case once the type is changed by the customer service team via omni-channel.
Never worked.
Did someone succeed ?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of omnichannel starts once the case is assigned to a queue.
And assignment rules are fired once is the case is created to assign it to specific queue or a user.

So, in all :

1. AR is fired first
2. If AR is satisfied it will assign to user or queue
3. If assigned to user no question of Omni channel
4. If assigned to a queue, then 2 more scenarios:
   i. If Queue is not configured with Routing Configuration then it is not considered as Omni channel queue and case remains in the queue
   ii. If Queue is configured with Routing Configuration then it is a Omni channel queue and now omni channel will route the case to the agent.
   a. If queue based-routing then agent in that queue if it is available and has the capacity to accept the case then case is routed to him
   b. If skill based-routing then agent with required skill is available and has capacity to accept the case then case is routed to him

**In a nutshell, AR fires first and then Omni channel**